# iPhone SDK: Adding text to a MKMapView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I just want to add some text to a MKMapView (dynamically in code). It seems like one way to go would be subclassing MKShape and defining a custom annotation (i.e. one without a pin or any other graphics) but I'm uncertain how to do it. Also, it seems like it might be possible to layer another control on top of the MKMapView that would allow me to add text.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a UILabel as a subview of the map?